# Apache2 not serving django content

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, apache2, celery

I am taking over a django project which another developer maintained. The service is run on an Ubuntu machine. ZEO is used for content caching. Ajax/Dajax is used for asynchronious content. Celery is used for task management and Django is used for the project itself.

The service is usually reached via a specific IP address which limits access to specific URLs. http://my_server_ip. Without knowingly changing anything, this started to not work. Instead of taking me to the splash page, entering the IP would hang, unsuccesfully connecting. I don't get a 404, 500 or some other error, it just sits and continually tries to load as if waiting to connect or to receive content.

I attempted to restart the service in the hopes that this would solve the problem, it did not. I performed a system reboot and followed the following commands, as per the prior developer's documentation, to reboot the server.

From within the django project:

```
runzeo -a localhost:8090 -f /path/to/operations_cache.fs
su project_owner
python manage.py celery worker -n multiprocessing_worker --loglevel=debug -Q multiprocessing_queue
python manage.py celery worker --concurrency=500 --pool=eventlet --loglevel=debug -Q celery -n eventlet_worker
```

The two celery commands had to be run as the owner of the project directory.

Finally I ran `sudo service apache2 restart`. Upon completion, I tried to navigate to the webpage but received the same response: hung on connecting. The trac pages do work at http://my_server_ip/trac.

The following is all I have found in the apache log files.

`error.log`

```
[Fri Feb 06 16:01:11 2015] [error] /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configobj.py:145: DeprecationWarning: The compiler package is deprecated and removed in Python 3.x.
[Fri Feb 06 16:01:11 2015] [error]   import compiler
[Fri Feb 06 16:01:11 2015] [error]
```

`access.log`

```
my.ip - user [06/Feb/2015:15:55:40 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 632 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:35.0 Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
```

I have tried looking into the django logs, but nothing appears there. Perhaps I am not finding the correct logs.

As a good start, where can I find out what the system is hanging on. How do I determine if it is an issue with django, apache, the interaction between the two, etc. This would help me zero in on specifically what is happening.

**Edit**

I was able to resolve my problem, though I cannot say for sure what resolved the issue. I suspect that the issue had to do with permissions on the static files folder. I serve my content through the www-user. After going through the steps described above I then ran `yes yes | python manage.py collectstatic` as the user `www-data`. The server was able restart and I was able to access the trac content as well as the django content.

I am hesitant to post this as an answer because I do not know with certainty whether my solution described here is the step which solved the problem.

Comment: You cano run `./manage.py runserver` and that should tell you if there is a problem with your django setup. You should try using 'curl` on it as well to see what the response is, assuming it starts up.

Comment: Unfortunately this has the exact same behvior.

Comment: What's the error? The same "import compiler" error?

Comment: It doesn't give any error. The import compiler error came from the error.log for apache. Running the server as django doesn't give any apache logs. Entering in the IP and port leaves the browser at the loading page.